# How do I correctly set up canvas capable on running a simulation

Tags: java, multithreading, class, oop

I'm brand new to Java and have only recently learnt about object oriented programming. I'm trying to create a program which can run a simulation, the general idea is that I want a part of the screen dedicated to buttons/sliders and another part to be dedicated the the Canvas running the simulation. For now I'm not worried about the simulation itself, I'm just trying to get some graphics on the canvas (which is smaller than the JFrame).

Here is my code (I'll try to leave some explanation below it)

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Display display = new Display();

    }

}
```

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display {

    public final int width = 1280, height = 720;
    public final int cwidth = 894, cheight = 504;
    public final String title = "Mechancis Simulator";
    private JFrame frame;
    //private JPanel panel;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Simulation simulation;

    public Display(){

        initDisplay();

        simulation = new Simulation();

    }

    private void initDisplay(){

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /*panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(width, height);
        panel.setLocation(0,0); */

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cwidth, cheight));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(cwidth, cheight));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(cwidth, cheight));
        canvas.setLocation(width - (cwidth +15), 15);

        //panel.add(canvas);
        frame.add(canvas);

        /* Add code for buttons/sliders/boxes here */

        /* Add these to panel */

    }

    public JFrame getFrame(){
        return frame;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas(){
        return canvas;
    }

}
```

.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Simulation extends Display implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    public Simulation(){

    }

    private void init(){

    }

    private void tick(){

    }

    private void render(){
        bs = getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //Draw Here!


        //End Drawing!
        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void run(){

        init();

        while(running){
            tick();
            render();
        }

        stop();

    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the program the window starts going crazy. I'm quite new to classes and threading so maybe that is the problem. I just want to be able to run the simulation after setting up Frame and Canvas in the Display object.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you expect `class Simulation` **`extends Display`** would help you with?

Comment: Swing is mostly not thread safe:  Most Swing methods can only be safely called from an application's Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  That is to say, they can only be safely called from event handlers.   If you want to animate something on the screen, you can use a `Timer` to schedule a task that the EDT will perform once in the future or, at regular intervals in the future.

Comment: If your `Simulation` does a lot of computation and needs to run in a background thread, then it can invoke `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(t)` to ask the EDT to perform some task `t` that will do the painting.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Sorry I'm quite new to objects and classes. I know that I could have declared a new Display object within the Simulation class however I thought that If I did this it would be referring to a different Display object (not the one from the launcher), I was under the impression that this would lead to creating an additional JFrame or something. If I could make Simulation an extension from Display then I wouldn't need to declare a new display object in order to access getCanvas(). I'm know most likely wrong here however I'm not really sure why.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing basically is this:

```
class Display {
    private final Simulation sim;
    public Display() { sim = new Simulation(); }
}

class Simulation extends Display {
    public Simulation() { }
}
```

when you create a new `Display` the constructor creates a new `Simulation` which is a `Display` which creates a new `Simulation` which is a `Display` which creates a new `Simulation` which is a `Display` which creates a new `Simulation`...*

So don't. There's no reason for your `Simulation` to be a display and to own another `Simulation`. If you want all the control in `Display` define a constructor that takes as an argument the `Simulation` it's displaying and give it a simulation when you create it:

```
class Display {
    private final Simulation sim;
    public Display(Simulation sim) { this.sim = sim; }
}

class Simulation {
}

...

Display display = new Display(new Simulation());
```

*I suggest you google for a tutorial on inheritance, if you wish to know more. Here's the [tutorial from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to get you started: *"You can write a subclass constructor that invokes the constructor of the superclass, either **implicitly** or by using the keyword super."* In your code example the constructor `super()` is invoked implicitly.